# Make div always fit inside static image section

Tags: html, css

I have a background image which contains a chalk board, and I am adding text onto the board, but the text has to be in HTML and cannot be part of the picture.

My issue is that depending on the screen size, by background image changes, and the position of the chalk board in the image changes too.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="html-content">
   <p>Test content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
  background-image: url('https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/thumbnail/0kjHIH6/videoblocks-cartoon-blackboard-in-a-children-classroom-with-a-school-bus_rp7t1bnse_thumbnail-full01.png');
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.html-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
}

.html-content p {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[How it looks like now](https://jsfiddle.net/3yrsp34e/)

What is the best way to make it so that no matter where the chalk board is on the image, the div will sit inside it.

Comment: Can you set max/min weight/height values, or you specifically want the blackboard to be dynamic?

Comment: chalk board is part of image. and div is already always inside board

Comment: i think u are using fixed width and height , so the image will be cropped in screen less than image width , am i right .

Comment: You could use the CSS3 funktion "calculate" im not sure but I think it could work.  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp

Answer (score 0):

As you've already specified the main `div`'s dimensions, it makes sense to specify the content `div`'s dimensions as well. Their locations are specified dynamically with percentages, so the window's dimensions shouldn't affect their relative positions to each other.

I aligned the inner `div` to the center of the chalkboard, so now it should be even easier to write on the whole board. You can toggle the inner `div`'s border, to see its exact dimensions.

```css
.main {
  background-image: url('https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/thumbnail/0kjHIH6/videoblocks-cartoon-blackboard-in-a-children-classroom-with-a-school-bus_rp7t1bnse_thumbnail-full01.png');
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.html-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 17%;
  left: 34%;
  width: 335px;
  height: 230px;
  text-align: center;
  /*border: 1px solid white;*/
}

.html-content p {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="html-content">
   <p>Test content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```